# How did Shaul consult the Urim and Tumim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul, bigdei-kehunah

During the events of chapters [27](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08a27)–31 of I *Sh'muel* (*David*'s stay among the *P'lishtim*), *David* had the *Urim V'sumim* with him, as is clear from [23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08a23):2–6 and from [30](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08a30):7–8. Yet in [28](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08a28):6, *Shaul* consults *Hashem* via the "*Urim*". *Radak* ad loc. wonders how he could have done so, inasmuch as he was not with the *Urim*, and says "maybe he sent men there [=to *David*] to ask". *M'tzudas David* says the same. *Bimchilas k'vodam*, this explanation is unsatisfying. After all, *Shaul* was out to get *David*: it seems odd that he'd send him a peaceful messenger. Does anyone know of any other explanation of 28:6 in light of the fact that the *Urim V'sumim* were with *David*?

Comment: At this point it's actually not so clear that Shaul wanted to kill David anymore: they had reconciled in 26:21, and (unlike their previous meeting, ch. 24) Shaul had given his word not to harm David. While indeed David had good reason to fear a change of heart on Shaul's part, that doesn't mean that there was one in fact. (Indeed, 27:4 states explicitly that Shaul gave up looking for David. See [Daas Soferim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39788&st=&pgnum=342), who suggests that Shaul indeed finally realized that his advisors had misled him into hating David without cause.)

Comment: And even if indeed Shaul still hated David, he still knew well enough to put the national needs ahead of his own - compare 23:26ff, where Shaul almost had David but gave up his pursuit of him in order to fight the Plishtim.

Comment: @Alex, re "even if... Shaul still hated David, he still knew... to put the national needs ahead of his": yes, but he thought _David_ was out to get him [again, as you note, perhaps no longer], so would I think unlikely send a messenger with a favor to ask.

Answer (score 6):

Ibn Ezra ([Shemot 28:6 *Peirush Aroch*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=458)) suggests that someone who was familiar with asking through the Urim VeTumim would be capable of getting answers on occasion from the Ephod. (I think he is referring to the two stones on the shoulders that clipped to the Choshen, but I'm not sure.)

Thus David used the Ephod (which we know he had, per [23:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a23.htm#6)) and Shaul used the Urim.

Comment: That fits well with Daas Soferim's idea (to I Sam. [23:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39788&st=&pgnum=297) and [28:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39788&st=&pgnum=348)) that there may have been more than one ephod, or that Shaul may have commissioned the making of another one.

Comment: Come to think of it, too, that also explains how the ephod that Gideon made (Judg. 8:27) ended up becoming an object of worship. I'd often wondered about that, since why would anyone ascribe divine powers to a garment? But with this explanation of Ibn Ezra's, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: possibly relevant http://mechon-mamre.org/i/8210.htm#13