# How many sets of Urim VeTumim were there?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, provenance, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-saul, bigdei-kehunah

On one TaNaKH passage, it seems both David (1 Samuel 30) and Shaul (1 Samuel 28) had access to an Urim VeTumim, suggesting there was more than one set of Urim VeTumim.

Hence my question: How many sets of Urim VeTumim were there?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15859/759

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Shaul consult the Urim and Tumim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15859/how-did-shaul-consult-the-urim-and-tumim)

Comment: @DoubleAA this "possible duplicate" does not answer my question, How many sets of Urim VeTumim were there?

Comment: @sabbahillel this "possible duplicate" does not answer my question: How many sets of Urim VeTumim were there?

Comment: @ninamag, the linked question does indirectly answer your question. Your question is based off of pesukim that imply there are multiple Urim VeTumim, while the answer there explains that the pesukim which imply multiple Urim VeTumim can be explaned as only referring to one set.

Comment: @Salmononius2 which pseukim are you referring to? The pesukim that I quoted, I only guessed, as suggesting more than one set of urim vtumim, but I would appreciate a clear rabbinical answer.

Comment: @ninamag You wrote Shmuel 30 and Shmuel 28 in your question. Both the question and the answer reference pesukim from those chapters, and give explanations for how those pesukim could be explained with only one set of Urim VeTumim. Based on that, there are no longer any Pesukim suggesting more than one set of Urim.

Comment: There is a comment on the answer that also points to a possibility of more than one ephod

Comment: @Salmononius2 I need a rabbinical answer.Still, sabbahillel's just now comment just went against what you just wrote. I can only ping one person at a time with my comment.

Comment: @sabbahillel "There is a comment on the answer that also points to a possibility of more than one ephod". Please put a link to this, so I can read it. Thank you.

Comment: possibly relevant http://mechon-mamre.org/i/8210.htm#13 – Double AA♦ Apr 21 '15 at 5:02

Comment: See [Daas Sofrim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39788&st=&pgnum=342)

Comment: @sabbahillel do these two links suggest that any ordinary kohen can administer the urim vtumim?

Comment: That was not part of the question. Since the Choshen Mishpat was part of the clothing of the kohen gadol, I doubt it. However, I do not have a source for my supposition.